# Django SimpleHistoryAdmin How to Change Custom Column Name

Tags: django, django-simple-history

In Django SimpleHistoryAdmin List View are 5 default columns (OBJECT, DATE/TIME, COMMENT, CHANGE_BY, CHANGE_REASON). I may add another column adding it to the `history_list_display` but name of this additional column is displayed as it's name in code, for example `first_name`. Is there an easy way to display it as `First Name`?

Answer (score 0):

the column will show the verbose_name defined in the field definition on the Model.

If you do not have access to the Model but to the ModelAdmin, you can try to do something like:

```
class SimpleHistoryAdmin(...):
    ...
    def _myfirst_name(self, instance):
        return instance.first_name

    _myfirst_name.short_description = "DESIRED FIELD LABEL"
```

You can user gettext and it's variants to provide translations for your custom label if needed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this before but it doesn't work for me. For ModelAdmin it works well but for HistoryAdmin not.

Comment: Can you include your SimpleHistoryAdmin code for reference?

Comment: Checking the source code seems that you can trick it using translations, it seems that there's nothing implemented to allow us to customize this :( -> https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history/blob/master/simple_history/templates/simple_history/_object_history_list.html

Comment: You are right. It seems the only way to do this goes over custom template (overriding `object_history_template`) and changed context.